# Main menu effect visited

Tags: html, css

I want to create an effect that when the user clicks on a menu item hover effect my stay.

This is my link:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

This is the CSS code for the full menu.

```
   .menu-item a img {
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: auto;
}
#menu-meniu >li {padding-left:80px;}
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered img.hovered-image,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered:hover img.menu-image {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered:hover img.hovered-image {
        opacity: 1;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-title-after.menu-image-not-hovered img,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered.menu-image-title-after .menu-image-hover-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
}
.menu-item a.menu-image-title-before.menu-image-not-hovered img,
.menu-item a.menu-image-hovered.menu-image-title-before .menu-image-hover-wrapper {
        padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Mention that use the plugin "Custom menu image" of Wordpress to create the menu.

I put a picture to see the admin panel you can create your own classes for each menu item ... maybe it help in solving the problem.

[image]

We found examples on W3Schools about how to do this job but I realize I do not class must apply the background when the user has selected item.

Can you help me with some advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'when the user navigates to page X by clicking it's menu button', you can use the `current_page_item` CSS class. Unless you want to modify the plugin code, I don't think it's possible unless you set the `current_page_item img {content:...}` per menu element.

Comment: pff fail to get along